Scratch org creation error- JwtGrantError
I'm getting below error while creating Salesforce scratch org-
Scratch org creation failed: 
 {
    "status": 1,
    "name": "JwtGrantError",
    "message": "We encountered a JSON web token error, which is likely not an issue with Salesforce CLI. Here’s the error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND usa20s.salesforce.com",
    "exitCode": 1,
    "commandName": "OrgCreateCommand",
    "stack": "JwtGrantError: We encountered a JSON web token error, which is likely not an issue with Salesforce CLI. Here’s the error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND usa20s.salesforce.com\n    at SfdxError.create (C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\sfdx-cli\\node_modules\\salesforce-alm\\node_modules\\@salesforce\\core\\lib\\sfdxError.js:141:16)\n    at C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\sfdx-cli\\node_modules\\salesforce-alm\\dist\\lib\\core\\force.js:204:32\n    at tryCatcher (C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\sfdx-cli\\node_modules\\bluebird\\js\\release\\util.js:16:23)\n    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\sfdx-cli\\node_modules\\bluebird\\js\\release\\promise.js:517:31)\n    at Promise._settlePromise (C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\sfdx-cli\\node_modules\\bluebird\\js\\release\\promise.js:574:18)\n    at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\sfdx-cli\\node_modules\\bluebird\\js\\release\\promise.js:619:10)\n    at Promise._settlePromises (C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\sfdx-cli\\node_modules\\bluebird\\js\\release\\promise.js:695:18)\n    at _drainQueueStep (C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\sfdx-cli\\node_modules\\bluebird\\js\\release\\async.js:138:12)\n    at _drainQueue (C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\sfdx-cli\\node_modules\\bluebird\\js\\release\\async.js:131:9)\n    at Async._drainQueues (C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\sfdx-cli\\node_modules\\bluebird\\js\\release\\async.js:147:5)\n    at Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\sfdx-cli\\node_modules\\bluebird\\js\\release\\async.js:17:14)\n    at process.processImmediate (node:internal/timers:483:21)",
    "warnings": []
}


This getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND usa20s.salesforce.com, indicates a DNS resolution issue where the Salesforce CLI cannot resolve the address usa20s.salesforce.com. This is often related to network or DNS configuration issues rather than a problem with the Salesforce CLI itself.
Verify your DNS settings and make sure you have installed the latest version of the Salesforce CLI.

ENOTFOUND usa20s.salesforce.com suggests that the domain name doesn't exist (ENOTFOUND means "Error: Not Found"). Checking on my computer, it agrees. Try authorizing your Dev Hub org again, and make sure you're using the correct username for the target-dev-hub configuration. If the problem persists, log an issue on the SFDX CLI repo for additional support.
